# Android detect the image is png/jpg/etc extension from the web

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview

I have to read the image from my website. However, the images uploaded by users in the server have variety extensions. jpg png etc. How I can modify the `image_url` code to detect the extension of the image automatically without having to declare it as static

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

    // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;

    editTxtQuantity = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputQuantity);

    btnAddtocart = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddtocart);
    btnCancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    productErrorMsg = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_error);

    txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    txtPrice = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    txtDesc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Imageview to show
    image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Getting productid from ScanFragment
    pid = getArguments().getString("pid");

    // Image url
    String image_url = "http://smartqr.droid-addict.com/upload/products/" + pid +".png"; 

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

This is because the name of the image file is not fixed. So how can I display it properly the image with its correct extension.

Comment: did you have full Name of the image? filename + extension?

Comment: get all file names from "http://testing-123.com/upload/products/" then check if its your file with `startsWith(pid)` then download it.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes, now I pid+png. I have to convert the all images to png. for examples. pid= 0001 hence 0001.png. Now i want it to automatically display the image regardless its extension.

Answer (score 4):

You just check your `Image_url` ends with `.png` or not by using `.endsWith(....)` method of `String` like

```
if(image_url.endsWith(".png")){
//your image ends with .png

}else if(image_url.endsWith(".jpg")){
//your image  ends with .jpg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use `String.endsWith` method to do so see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) link for better understanding.

```
String image_url = "http://testing-123.com/upload/products/" + pid +".png";

if(image_url.endsWith("png"))
{
  // do something
}
else if(image_url.endsWith("jpg"))
{
  // do something
}
else if(image_url.endsWith("bmp"))
{
  // do something
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but we have declared it as .png for image_url. will endsWith method still check for other extension? of course it will go for image_url.endsWith("png").

Comment: can you please explain the reason why you should declare it as .png? @MarkJue

Comment: According to your answer, you still declare image_url as String image_url = "http://testing-123.com/upload/products/" + pid +".png"; the endsWith method still check for other extension? since we have declared it as .png?

Comment: i have declare as per your url declaration in question.

Comment: You should check extension rather than declaring its static extension.

Comment: @Andrain PO is still confuse what he want?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best way, If you are selecting an image from device.**

...

```
 /*
     * Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent, then
     * get the file's MIME type
     */


Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData();

String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(returnUri);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#java
...