# Most efficient way to check if image used to create bitmap was .PNG - Android

Tags: android, transparency, android-bitmap

Given a bitmap object I want to determine if the image I used to create the Bitmap was in .PNG or .JPG format. I wrote the below code to determine that. I perform a scaling operation to the bitmap and then search pixel by pixel to find if there is any transparent pixel. Is there any better way to do that?

```
public static boolean isBitmapPNG(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int scaledWidth=20;
    int scaledHeight=20;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = resizeBitmap(bitmap,scaledWidth,scaledHeight);

    for (int x=0;x<scaledBitmap.getWidth();x++)
        for (int y=0;y<scaledBitmap.getHeight();y++)
            if (((scaledBitmap.getPixel(x,y) & 0xff000000) >> 24)==0)
                return true;
             
   return false;     
}


public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float)maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        return image;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987743/android-detect-the-image-is-png-jpg-etc-extension-from-the-web#:~:text=public%20View%20onCreateView(LayoutInflater%20inflater,inflate(R.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper This link shows how to check if a String has an ending of .jpg or .png. I am asking about Bitmap object.

Comment: Bitmaps are bitmaps. They have nothing to do with being png, jpg, gif, tiff, svg ... Please explain why they would.

Comment: @blackapps If a Bitmap has transparent pixels, then the image we converted into the Bitmap object was in .PNG format.

Comment: @blackapps but I get your point. I shouldn't ask if the bitmap is .png. I should ask about transparent pixels.

Comment: You should ask if the bitmap came from loading a png file. If you could determine that it was not from loading  a jpg. Further you resize to 20x20 from i.e. 2345x1234. I think by throwing away so much pixels you are throwing away so much info. And if you create a bitmap from nothing and there are transparant pixels -or you just make some transparant- and you compress it to jpg then was the bitmap png? Strange world.

Comment: @blackapps I edited my post. I resize the image to increase the efficiency. I get correct results, so I guess it is a strange world.

Comment: Nice question. Again something learned. Thanks.

Comment: "Given a bitmap object I want to determine if the image I used to create the Bitmap was in .PNG or .JPG format" -- that's not really possible in a reliable fashion. First, the image could have come from other formats besides those, or from sources that never originated in a file. Second, you are assuming that every PNG has transparent pixels, that those pixels survive a scaling operation, and that no other image format has transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`bitmap.hasAlpha()` method .
If it returns true then it is a png.
If not then jpg.